# How to calculate missclass rate column after several predictions?

Tags: python

i am trying to find a way to calculate the misclassification rate after running through several prediction iterations as below. I have attempted to write the remaining code but it still doesn't work. what am I doing wrong?

```
predictions = df.copy()
y = df['gt']
noiter = 10
hits = 0
tpred = 0

for i in range(noiter):
    Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(df,test_size=0.3,random_state=noiter)


    model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
    model.fit(X_train,y_train)
    pred_i = model.predict(X_test)
    newcol = 'npred_' + str(noiter)
    pred.loc[test.index,newcol] = pred_i

#now to calculate the misclassification rate
    if pred_i != 'NaN':
        tpred = tpred + 1


    if pred_i == test['gt']:
        hits = hits + 1

pred['missclassrate'] = hits/tpred
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the confusion matrix to determine false positive and negatives:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print confusion_matrix(ytest, pred_i)
```

Comment: thanks but i would like to have a separate column in the dataframe which will calculate the misclassification for each sample. i think this part pred['missclassrate'] = hits/tpred should be within the for loop as well so that it calculates for each not for overall